# How do I replace one layer with another and take all its specifications

Tags: after-effects, animation

How do I replace one layer with another and take all its specifications(size, scale, position, effects....) in after effects?.

Answer (score 1):

1. Select the layer you want to replace in the timeline or comp window
2. <kbd>Alt/opt</kbd>-drag the new source from the project window into the comp or timeline window.